# Где найти опцию импорта библиотек ("Import Type Library") в Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

В Delphi 7 была такая опция `Project->Import Type Library`. Куда она подевалась в `Delphi XE (RAD Studio)`?

Comment: а ответить слабо)?

Comment: Ну первая ссылка в гугле же [Importing Type Library Information](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Importing_Type_Library_Information)

Comment: по-русски есть что-нибудь?

Comment: Никогда так не делайте )

Answer (score 4):

В RAD оно заменилось на целый диалог импорта. 
Меню Component => Пункт "Import Component..." и импортируйте.

Answer (score 0):

Main menu->Component->Import Component

Comment: Чем по сути ваш ответ отличается от данного семь лет назад? У нас не очень принято дублировать одинаковые ответы.